# Powershell opening vscode with "code ." changes terminal color

Tags: visual-studio-code, powershell-core

This falls in between Powershell and vs code - I think.

Note: I am on a mac terminal and opening pwsh(Powershell) - where I have create a mac terminal profile, using blue colors.

I have setup the terminal profile - Powershell colors following [this](https://sqlsunday.com/2019/03/04/how-to-set-up-a-beautiful-powershell-core-terminal-on-mac-os/)

Then when I open vscode with "code ." from within Powershell(pwsh)it changes back colors for the terminal starting the vscode.

Do you know where it I can change this?

Comment: It's unclear to me to ***what*** terminal you do refer, the VSCode `Powershell Integrated Console` ?

Comment: Thanks, just tried to make it more clear - I hope.

Comment: Can you post screenshots? As it is, your question is vague.